# After Effects slow animation

Tags: after-effects, animation, animation-rendering

I f****d up and changed the framerate of my AE preview because the project began taking its toll on my computer, mistakenly thinking that this will increase performance. However I sadly had to notice (after continuing to work on my project for quite some time) that this only affects the playback speed. And herein lies my problem: Everything is twice as fast as I had animated it. As a workaround I simply put everything in a precomp and enabled time-remapping, however this feels more like some makeshift solution rather than something proper.

Now here is my question: Is there a way to tell after effects to stretch everything (layer length, keyframes, etc.) so that they are of correct length? Or do I have to rework everything manually what will probably make me never forget the difference between skipped frames and framerate again? :D

Comment: Only for key frames on a particular layer, but you can select all within a certain layer an alt drag them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to recommend nesting the comp and use time-remapping actually, which of course you came up with as the solution.

I think, to be honest, this is your best bet, or time remap each layer in your existing composition.

Doing the time-remap on your original comp, has the advantage that the keyframes will in fact be at the correct place given whatever time-base you want to end up in. This will allow for, if say your time-base is higher, more discrete frames, or points, in which to place new keyframes.

Doing a remap in a nested comp will limit your ability to add keyframes in between what would be 2 frames... being your master comp (parent) only has 1 keyframe and therefor cannot be divided.

Try time-remapping the composition; after you adjust the composition settings to the correct timebase. I don't see why that wouldn't give you what you need.

Comment: Even worse, the shutter angle/motion blur will play a role here